# How to rename an uploaded file before it is saved?

Tags: php, file, rename

I am using this snippet below to get the filename and extension, which works, but how can i rename the file so that filename will equal bake23 + the extension of the file.

```
  $variable = 'baKe23';


  $filename = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
  $ext = $_FILES["filename"]["type"];
```

Rename if a filename already exists:

```
       $filename = $_FILES['filename']['name']; 
  $extension = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), 
  strlen($filename)-1);

         $sql="SELECT filename FROM documents WHERE person_id= '$pid'";  

     $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

    if ($result == "")
    {
    echo "";
     }
    echo "";


   $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

   if($rows == 0)
   {
  print("");

   }
   elseif($rows > 0)
   {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {

  $existing = $row['filename'];

  print("");
   }

    }

    if ( $filename === $existing ) {
$filename = $rnd_id.strrchr($_FILES['filename']['name'], ".");

   } else {
   $filename = $_FILES['filename']['name'];;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the extension from the submitted filename and add it to your variable:

```
$filename = basename($filename);
$filename = $variable . (string) strrchr($filename, '.');
```

**Edit:** For your edited question, *literally*:

```
$filename =  $variable . '.' . $ext;
```

However, considering I would be uploading an image called `banana-smiley.gif`, the following would happen:

```
$filename = 'baKe23.image/gif';
```

This is not what you want I assume. You should not even rely on `$_FILES[*]["type"]` at all. What you need to do is inspect each uploaded file (determine the type, validate the type, run a virus checker on the uploaded file).

Question related to this are [**Secure File Upload and validating it**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640778/secure-file-upload-and-validating-it) and [**Is it important to verify that the uploaded file is an actual image file?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391916/is-it-important-to-verify-that-the-uploaded-file-is-an-actual-image-file/6392063).

Comment: @KPO: It's the mime-type, not the file-type (extension). You probably are looking for a map from mime-type to file-extension. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php for a list of all the keys in `$_FILES`.

Comment: i am using this to avoid duplicate file names.  do you think its better if i instead of renaming give each document a new folder within the users folder?

Comment: @KPO: Instead of a folder you can just prefix the files, or start to number them if a file of the same name already exists. But I would prefix them with some shorter random sequence, so filenames on disk are not predictable that easily.

Comment: @hakre thanks again.  i did try to do a rename script but it doesn't work and instead changes all file upload names.  Can you check, i have posted what i used.

Answer (score 3):

```
$variable = 'baKe23';
$filename = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
$filename = $variable.strrchr($_FILES['filename']['name'], ".");
```

or

```
$variable = 'baKe23';
$filename = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
$filename = $variable.".".pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: @KingCrunch: changed already. You should wait before downvoting a bit. just a mistake

Comment: If you've got a malicious file name submitted, the strrchr variant can be fooled to inject path patterns into the new name. I came to the conclusion it's best to combine strrchr and basename now.

Comment: i am using this to avoid duplicate file names.  do you think its better if i instead of renaming give each document a new folder within the users folder?

Comment: @KPO: I think it will be better to create md5() value for these files