# Downloading remote image via php (securely)

Tags: php, jquery

PHP:

Any ideas where I could find a script similar to what stackoverflow uses? Or would it be easy to make something like that myself? I'm sure downloading the image is not a problem, but I'm more worried about security. I'm building an user avatar upload/remote upload system.

Jquery:

The reason I added jquery to the tags, perhaps it is possible to let the user point the URL of the image and somehow upload it via the normal file upload input himself (without having to manually download the image to the computer first)

Comment: ??? What exactly are your challenges ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching a file on a server, resizing with PHP GD2, security considerations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606951/fetching-a-file-on-a-server-resizing-with-php-gd2-security-considerations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to download the image and then use [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to check whether it's actually an image - for security purposes.

```
<?php
$limit = 1024*1024*10 // Max. file size in bytes (1024*1024*10 = 10MB)
$ch = curl_init();

$fh = fopen('image.jpg', 'w'); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, '0-' . $limit);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if ($image = getimagesize ("image.jpg")) { 
     // It's an image
}
else { 
     // Not an image; delete!
}
```

Comment: Dangerous - you've not set any limits on how much data to fetch, so a hostile user can put in a link that leads to a multi-terabyte download. curl supports streaming a download to file, plus fetch limits

Comment: Thanks, I can actually point this to my local upload script and not code duplicate verification scripts.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further though? Say $url is the url sent by the user. In your example I would just have to replace image.jpg with the $url? The reason I'm asking is because URLOPT_URL also seems to contain a variable.

Comment: No, $url is the image the user provides and image.jpg is the file youre saving to