# Cross site file upload with php authentication

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, file-upload

I have two domain names (in two hosting locations). `Domain 1` is a normal website with authentication. I am using `Domain 2` as a place to just upload files (for storage). I am using `angular-file-upload` https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload from client side.

My backend code is super simple and it is current working .. but without any form of authentication.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
  //The error validation could be done on the javascript client side.

  $errors= array();        
  $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];   
  $file_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png", "gif");        

  if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions ) === false){
   $errors[]="image extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }
  if($file_size > 2097152){
  $errors[]='File size cannot exceed 2 MB';
  }     

  if(empty($errors)==true){

    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
    echo $fname . " uploaded file: " . "images/" . $file_name;
  }else{
    print_r($errors);
  }
}
?>
```

**Questions:**

1. How to make sure the user is authenticated in `Domain 1` before they can upload files? I mean I could just change `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` but someone can easily go to Chrome Developer and do a POST upload from custom javascript.
2. Is there a way to do `#1` without getting overly complicated? Is it possible to pass some cookie values?

I have full control of both hosting sites so I can do whatever I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Upload file enhance security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751384/php-upload-file-enhance-security)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sharing a common secret**

One way is to **share a secret**, wich is only known to **Site A** and **Site B**.

Suppose Site A and Site B know a **common complex and non-predictable string** `salt` [[randomness source]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830839/generating-cryptographically-secure-tokens).

If Site A authenticates a user, A creates a random string `rndA`, a `valueThrough` timestamp and then computes a hash like so:

```
   sharedHash = hash( rndA + salt + valueThrough )
```

- Site A hands over this tuple to the client: `[ sharedHash, valueThrough , randA ]`
- The clients hands over this tuple to Site B
- Site B then **verifies the client's rights** using the same hash() operation.

If B **computes the same sharedHash** and the current **timestamp is still smaller than valueThrough**, client gets authenticated.

**Letting Site A and Site B talk to each other**

Alternatively, Site A and Site B might talk directly to each other:

- Site A hands over a security token to the client
- Client hands over the security token to Site B
- Site B then verifies the token by directly talking to Site A

While this technique requires reachability of Site A <-> Site B, the former technique even works, if Site A and Site B can't exchange HTTP-requests directly.

In both cases [Generating cryptographically secure tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830839/generating-cryptographically-secure-tokens) might be of interest.

*Other and stronger techniques certainly exist.*

Answer (score 1):

How's about sharing session in db like redis or mongodb?